# Why does sqrt calculation take longer than pythagoras?

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

I recently tried to benchmark the performance of several JavaScript engines to check the performance of a sorting algorithm I wrote. In the process I stumbled across a behaviour I can't explain. In V8 and Spidermonkey the pythagoras function is calculated mostly within the same time as sqrt sometimes EVEN FASTER! Since sqrt is part of the calculation I would assume it should be much slower over 10000000 iterations ... It seems only in Chakra pythagoras is consitently calculated about 3-4 seconds slower.

computer:

- OS : Win 10 64 Bit
- CPU : i5-8250U 4 core
- RAM : 8 GB

with latest available versions of each browser at this time (Chrome, Firefox and Edge)

Here is my benchmark script:

```
var out = document.getElementById("output")

var start, temp,
    lat1 = 14, lat2 = 28, lon1 = 12, lon2 = 24,
    steps = 10000000

start = Date.now()

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    temp = Math.sqrt(lat2)
}

out.innerHTML += '<div> sqrt : ' + (Date.now() - start) + '</div>'

// pythagoras

start = Date.now();

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    temp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lat2 - lat1, 2) + Math.pow(lon2 - lon1, 2))
}

out.innerHTML += '<div> pythagoras : ' + (Date.now() - start) + '</div>'
```

PS: the setRandomLatLon() almsot consistentently takes around 122 ms (in V8 at least)

Comment: Because you're not doing the square root for the same numbers and calculations for different numbers take varying amounts of time? (28-14)+(24-12) => 14+12 => 26 while your "pure" square root is calculated for 28.

Comment: shouldn't this also cause the pythagoras function to be calculated slower? Yet is it sometimes calculated faster ...

Comment: On top of that, you are doing the _exact same_ calculation ten million times over - so it is easily imaginable that the engine does some Memoization here; but maybe not in both cases, but based on same heuristic that checks how “complex” the expression is beforehand or something like that … I just somehow doubt that this is a _proper_ test case.

Comment: Change the number inside the loop. This way temp is not cached. The JIT-compiler is smart enough to not recalculate the same thing 10000000 times.

Comment: that's a good point. I changed my example and tested it. Still however I occasionally get a faster result for pythagoras ... but I guess it might be related to the CPU being to busy in that moment of testing ...

Comment: You're doing integer calculations which means that `pow` doesn't really do anything. Depending on how it's optimized that function call might not even exist. A square root can be calculated in various ways. You might have a lookup table for common numbers and/or (without checking into it) the calculation for the square root of 26 might just be faster than for 28 (needing fewer operations).

Comment: I'll vary the numbers for each iteration and check again (was suspecting something like the numbers being "cached" as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggested solutions. The test case now seems to work properly (considering it produces the expected results).

The main change now was to vary the used lat, lon values with each iteration using a function that almost always executes over the same amount of time.

The final code (setRandomLatLon takes in V8 around 120 ms over 10000000 iterations):

```
var out = document.getElementById("output")

var start, temp,
    lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2,
    steps = 10000000

function setRandomLatLon(){
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*12);
    lat1 = rand + 2
    lat2 = rand + 12
    lon1 = rand + 4
    lon2 = rand + 14
}

// pythagoras    

start = Date.now()

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    setRandomLatLon()
    temp = Math.sqrt(lat2)
}

out.innerHTML += '<div> sqrt : ' + (Date.now() - start) + '</div>'

// pythagoras

start = Date.now();

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    setRandomLatLon()
    temp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lat2 - lat1, 2) + Math.pow(lon2 - lon1, 2))
}

out.innerHTML += '<div> pythagoras : ' + (Date.now() - start) + '</div>'
```